# JBPM - NPE while trying to populate top level variable with sub variable

Tags: jbpm, kie-workbench

I've been attempting for a while to find a solution to creating a project over-view for my jbpm project. We hope to use the REST remote API to pull back all of the variable data which exists within our project.

At this time I've been attempting to periodically set a top-level model variable with a model variable in my sub-processes, using syntax like this in a script task:

```
kcontext.setVariable("TopLevelVariable", SubVariable);
```

The idea behind this concept is to allow us to use a consistent process id to query a single variable for a project overview.

This syntax gives me an NPE, however, which I'd like to understand. I assume that 'TopLevelVariable' is inaccessible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you making the appropriate data mappings?

Answer (score 0):

What we ended up doing with our project was defining a basic workflow structure in jbpm 6.1 which was devoid of forms and data processing. When a project was started we queried for process tasks on our front end and displayed a custom form based on the task name. This was accomplished while leveraging marionette/backbone.

On our front end we then created a project id which was referenced in our own database table. We passed that project id into the workflow and mapped it throughout the entire jbpm workflow, so all tasks in a particular 'project' aka process instance had access to the project id, which would be used to query data from our own database across the entire project.